# c - understanding fixed point bit model

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, fixed-point

So I'm learning about binary values and I'm trying to understand how to calculate the negative version of a number using the fixed point bit model.

In my textbook it says 000111.01 = 7.25 which I understand. But it's telling me -7.25 is 111000.11 which I don't understand how that's possible.

I know it's using the two's complement rule where it flips all the bits and adds a 1 at the end. But if I did the calculation: (1 * 2^5) + ( 1 * 2^4) + (1 & 2^3) + 0 + 0 + 0 + (1 * 2^-1) + ( 1 * 2^-2) it gives me 56.75.

I tried looking up tutorials online but I still can't figure out why -7.25 is 111000.11. I would appreciate it if someone could explain the mathematical process behind getting -7.25.

Comment: The bit weights are -32,16,8,4,2,1,0.5,0.25. So it's -32+16+8+0.5+0.25 = -7.25

Comment: Can I ask why 32 is negative?

Comment: Because it's the sign bit.

Comment: Like I've seen examples for numbers like -89.25 and only 128 was negative. How do I determine what bit weights are negative under which circumstances?

Comment: So basically the first bit is always negative?

Comment: Yes, the most significant bit of a two's complement number has a negative weight. All the other bits are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an signed 8-bit 6Q2 format fixed point representation having a resolution of 2<sup>-2</sup> (or 0.25).  You can look at this purely arithmetically:

The `int8_t` value of 11100011 is -29, but with the fixed point scaling that is -29 x 0.25 = -7.25.

Or then in terms of 2's compliment bit values which for an 8 bit *integer* are:

-2<sup>7</sup> (-128<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>6</sup> (64<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>5</sup> (32<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>4</sup> (16<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>3</sup> (8<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>2</sup> (4<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>1</sup> (2<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>0</sup> (1<sub>10</sub>)

but the Q2 fixed point shifts those place values by 2 as follows:

-2<sup>5</sup> (-32<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>4</sup> (16<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>3</sup> (8<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>2</sup> (4<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>1</sup> (2<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>0</sup> (1<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>-1</sup> (0.5<sub>10</sub>)
 2<sup>-2</sup> (0.25<sub>10</sub>)

Answer (score 2):

> *I know it's using the two's complement rule where it flips all the bits and adds a 1 at the end.*

Under a scale factor where the binary point has been moved left two places, you need a modified rule: flip all the bits and add 1/4, or 0.01.

```
000111.01 = 7.25
```

Flip all the bits:

```
111000.10
```

Add `0.01`:

```
111000.11
```

All that the fixed point convention has done is move the binary point. If we multiply `111000.11` by 4 (and truncate to stay within 8 bits), we get `100011.00`. And that is -29. Exactly four times -7.25. Therefore if we *divide* 29 by 4, the process must reverse and go from `100011.00` to `111000.11`. That's simply an **arithmetic shift right**. The process of **sign extension** is filling in 1's from the top, and the other bits are just shifting down. We end up with the `.11`.

Of course, here when I say "divide by 4", I mean divide by the regular integer 4, not the scaled 4 = 100.00. Under fixed point, we can use regular, un-adjusted multiplication and division to combine a fixed operand with a regular operand. FIXED x INT -> FIXED just uses regular multiplication. FIXED + FIXED -> FIXED uses regular addition. FIXED x FIXED -> FIXED requires renormalization. FIXED + INT -> FIXED requires conversion of the INT to FIXED.